# Are insert in Oracle sequential

Tags: sql, oracle, concurrency

I have a table in Oracle.
I am creating multiple Batch jobs.
Each Batch job is inserting some number of records in the table.

I wanted to know whether there insert statements are sequential executed ?

Comment: Playing the devil's advocate, can you even guarantee that your various batch inserts will even hit the Oracle database at the same time?

Comment: There might be a possibility, that why I asked the question.

Comment: Who is creating these batch jobs?  Is it a process within Oracle, or is it coming from external, e.g. from software?

Comment: You can add a `SYSTIMESTAMP` column in your table and insert `SYSTIMESTAMP`  through the batches to check out which batch is getting executed at what time,this way you can check the sequence.

Comment: Process within Oracle

Comment: If those inserts are run from different connections, then they are executed in parallel (assuming the server can handle the load from a performance point of view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In particular job, if it's runs in one transaction answer is 'YES', but if you want to find out sequence through all jobs , which starts same time, it all depends of particular situation and you jobs implementation. For example if we have 2 jobs  and one them starts earlier then other, but first one needs more time to collect data then we can't say that first job inserts will be done earlier then second.  There are many factors which affect to order of records insert. So if it's critical for you to control order then you should implement consistency yourself, using timestamp checks or object locks.